# Passing php array as variables to javascript load url and back to php array?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, url, joomla

I saw many examples related but I'm still confused. I'm using ajax (which I don't know much about) to get the results of a file updated every xxx seconds. It's working perfectly if I pass just one variable, but what is the best way if I need to pass an array from php through it?

Structure is simples:

```
show_results.php

<?php
include_once('modWhosonlineCustom.inc.php');
$document->addScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js");
$document->addScript("ajax.js");
$array_name = modWhosonlineCustom::getOnlineUserNames();//the array I need to pass to javascript variable
?>

<script>
var whosonline = '<?php echo "$array_name"; ?>';
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Ajax code than would have more than one param to build in the url load:

```
  ajax.js

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load("response.php?array_name[param1]&array_name[param2]");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  $("#results").load("response.php?array_name[param1]&array_name[param2]&randval="+ Math.random());
  }, 10000);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  });
```

And back to PHP response page, how could I use again the array params passed through url?

```
  response.php

  <?php
  $names = $_GET['array_name'];
  foreach ($names as $name) {
  //do something
```

Any suggestions is really appreciated, thanks!

EDIT

Thanks guys, I think I'm the right way now, but ramains the problem to pass this array through a url in the javascript. Or maybe I'm not getting it in the right way in the php end callback file. I'll show you what a modifyed:

```
   show_results.php

   ...
   <?php
   $names = modWhosonlineCustom::getOnlineUserNames();
   ?>

   <script>
   var whosonline = '<?php echo "json_encode($names)"; ?>';
   </script>


   ajax.js


   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#atendentes").load("response.php?names=" + whosonline);
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
   $("#atendentes").load("response.php?names=" + whosonline + "&randval="+ Math.random());
   }, 10000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   });


   response.php


   $users = $_GET['names'];
   $users = json_decode($users);
   echo "user: $users";

   $names = $users;
   foreach ($names as $name) {
   ...
```

Here in the other side I'm getting: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in response.php on line 33, and the echo is empty

What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

To pass arrays/objects from PHP to JavaScript you may use the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json-encode)/[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json-decode) functions.

Comment: Thank you! I went through the manual and modifyed the script, but ramain the problem now on how to get the array again from the url generated by javascript. Please see the edited question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code wouldn't work. If you have

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo $arr;
```

you actually get

```
Array
```

as the output. Not the contents of the array. To "output" an array from PHP to JS, you have to convert it to native Javascript, which is where json_encode comes in:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
?>
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>;
```

which will produce

```
var js_array = ["a","b","c"];
```

As a general rule, anytime you are using PHP to generate javascript code and are filling in Javascript variables with PHP values, you should use json_encode to ensure that you're generating valid Javascript. Any syntax errors and the whole Javascript code block is dead in the water once the client starts trying to execute it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc B. I think my problem now is how to pass get the array back in the php callback file in a usable way. I'm editing my question with your suggestion to give you an idea, if you can give me another clue. Thanks!

Comment: There's [`JSON.stringify`](http://www.json.org/js.html) to do the JS-side equivalent of `json_encode()`, which could then url-encode and put into a query string... but consider using post to transfer this, as long query strings get truncated by browsers and servers.

Comment: Hi Mark B, how can I use POST to approuch this since the url is used to call the file to be updated automaticly? I don't know how to build a logic with this approuch, could you give me an example?