# How to pass nested foreach Values to CanvasJS chart?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas

I do some calculations with below Code and after that i want to pass the values to the Chart but i can not send them i have try this:

```
 $getStoreIDs = mysqli_query($dbConnection, "SELECT DISTINCT Stores_storeID FROM maintable WHERE Survey_surveyId = '$surveyID' ");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getStoreIDs))
             { 
                $storeIDarray[] = $row;

             }

    foreach($_POST['sections'] as $selected)
            {

        foreach ($storeIDarray as $key => $row)
            {
                $storeID = $row['Stores_storeID'];



                      $storeNames= mysqli_query($dbConnection , "SELECT storeName FROM stores WHERE storeID = '".$row['Stores_storeID']."'");
                     $sectinName = mysqli_query($dbConnection , "SELECT sectionName FROM sections WHERE sectionID = '$selected' ");


                    $totalSections = mysqli_query($dbConnection, "SELECT SUM(itemPrice) AS totalSection FROM maintable WHERE items_Family_Sections_sectionID='$selected' AND Stores_storeID = '$storeID' AND Survey_surveyId = '$surveyID' ");


                } 
            }
```

i want to pass the values of ($storeNames, $ectionName and $totalSelections)
and here is my CanvasJs code `

```
var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",
{
  title:{
    text: "Store Comparision"    
  },
  animationEnabled: true,
  axisY: {
    title: "Total Price"
  },
  legend: {
    verticalAlign: "bottom",
    horizontalAlign: "center"
  },
  theme: "theme2",
  data: [

  {        
    type: "column",  
    showInLegend: true, 
    legendMarkerColor: "grey",
    dataPoints: [  



    ]
  }   
  ]
});

chart1.render();`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing php array as variables to javascript load url and back to php array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943224/passing-php-array-as-variables-to-javascript-load-url-and-back-to-php-array)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put your javascript code before canvas chart,it renders.

How you are passing data to your view is important.Are you passing as json object or array?

If as json then need to parse in javscript before sending encoded in php.

In datapoints paraemeter you can pass like this

```
dataPoints: JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($json_managers) ?>)
```

Or can do via PHP before sending (A sample code snippet)

```
$managers = DB::table('orders')
    ->join('managers', 'orders.manager_id', '=', 'managers.id')
    ->groupBy('managers.manager_name')
    ->get(['managers.manager_name',DB::raw("sum(orders.sale) as sale")]);

    foreach($managers as $key => $value){
        $point = array("label" => $value->manager_name , "y" => $value->sale);
        array_push($data_manager_points, $point);
    }
    $json_managers = json_encode($data_manager_points,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

For more get here :

http://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/how-can-i-use-php-mysql-dynamic-data/

Comment: can you please check my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401860/canvas-js-data-sampling-in-php) related to canvasjs?